# Question regarding differentiability of function at x=0

Tags: calculus, derivatives

[image]

I removed the absolute signs ,but in D part how do i remove the outer absolute value symbol

Comment: You might observe that $\forall \alpha\ge0,\ e^{-\alpha}\le1$.

Comment: for $x<0 $ inner quantity of outer mod will be -ve and the function will be negative and for $x>0 $ this function will be positive you can check for continuity at 0- and 0+

Answer (score 1):

In part (D) just remark that $e^{-t} \leq 1$ for all $t \geq 0$. Take $t=|x|\geq 0$ and conclude that $|e^{-|x|}-1| = 1-e^{-|x|}$.